Probability of having a complete Graph
I thought of a random graph theory problem and was wondering if anyone has seen this or a similar problem before.
Assume we have $n$ vertices, and the probability of an edge existing between vertex $m$ and vertex $n$ is $\frac{1}{m+n}$, where $m \neq n$. If $m = n$, then there is no edge. My question is: what is the probability of a complete graph existing?
Let $K_{n}$ be a complete graph with $n$ vertices
I worked on this problem a little bit. For $n=2$, the probability is
$$
\frac{1}{1+2} = \frac{1}{3}
$$
For $n=3$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{5}
$$
This process can be generalized and we can express the probability $P(K_n)$ as:
$$
P(K_n) = \prod_{m=1}^{n-1} \prod_{i=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{m+i}
$$
I also noticed this recursive formula:
Assuming we have a complete graph $K_n$ and call the probability of it existing $P(K_n)$ then if we add in another vertex the probability of the new vertex being attached to every other vertex is
$$\prod_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{m+n+1}$$
multiply this to $P(K_n)$ and we get
$$
P(K_{n+1}) = P(K_{n}) \cdot \prod_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{m+n+1}
$$
Any suggestions on how I can go further with this problem? I am curious if there is a cleaner way to rewrite these formulas. If anyone has seen this problem or something similar I would love to hear about it to see how others have approached this.
I don't have a lot of experience in analysis but I feel like there is a way to prove(or disprove) the probability of a connected graph existing as $n$ approaches $\infty$ converges.
If $$a_n=P(K_n)$$ then $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|=\left|
\frac{P(K_{n+1})}{P(K_{n})}\right|=\left|\prod_{m=1}^n\frac{1}{m+n+1}\right|$$
any ideas on how to prove this convergence?
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\prod_{m=1}^n\frac{1}{m+n+1}\right|$$

Converge to 0 is simple since $\prod_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{m+n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ while $\prod_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{N!}$ approaches 0 as $N$ approaches $\infty$. Whether a closed-form formula exists is much more challenging to answer.

For a closed-form formula, Mathematica gives $$\frac{1}{P(K_n)} = \frac{\sqrt[8]{e} 2^{-n^2+n+\frac{1}{24}} \pi ^{\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4}} G(n+2)^{n-2} G(2 n+1) \left(\frac{\Gamma (n+2)}{G(n+3)}\right)^{n-1}}{A^{3/2} G\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) G(n+1)},$$ where $A$ is Glaisher–Kinkelin constant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant), $G$ is Barnes G-function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function), and $\Gamma$ is Gamma function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
